# Puppet/Hiera: hashed variable definition is not replaced

Tags: puppet, hiera

My yaml file contains a hashed definition, "nodemanager_instances". The value of the variable, 'nodemanager_port', is not replaced while I am executing puppet. In my common.yaml file, the value is defined. Can anyone find a reason why this is not working?

**mwpapp.yaml**

```
nodemanager_instances:
  'nodemanager':
    nodemanager_port: "%{domain_nodemanager_port}"
    domain_name:      "%{::sysfunc}"
```

**common.yaml**

```
domain_nodemanager_port: "5552"
```

**hiera.yaml**

```
:backends:
    - yaml

:yaml:
    :datadir: /etc/puppet/manifests/hiera

:hierarchy:
    - "hostname/%{::hostname}"
    - "sysfunc/%{::sysfunc}"
    - "appotap/%{::app}%{::otap}"
    - "otap/%{::otap}"
    - "domain/%{::domain}"
    - "colo/colo-%{::colo}"
    - "os/%{::operatingsystem}/%{::operatingsystem}-%{::operatingsystemrelease}"
    - "os/%{::operatingsystem}"
    - common/common
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you need Hiera `1.3` or later, and you must use [interpolation tokens](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/variables.html#interpolation-tokens) such as

```
    nodemanager_port: "%{hiera('domain_nodemanager_port')}"
```